# Route traffic on a specific port of an IPv4 server to an IPv6 target

Tags: linux, centos, networking

The situation is that I have an IPv6 server which should also be available from the IPv4 net. As getting an IPv4 onto this server is out of the question I need to route the traffic through a second server which acts as a router.

The following situation is present:

[image: An IPv4 device and an IPv6 server with no connection in between.]

Assuming that one wants to access an IPv6 server from an IPv4 network (for example most mobile ones) one is out of luck. There is no easy way to do that. However, I have the idea to use an intermediate server which exists on both networks and can route the traffic correctly:

[image: The IPv4 device and the IPv6 server talk through a middleman.]

I'm already in possession of such a server but I'm a little bit out of my depth when it comes to configuring the routing. The intermediate server is only possessing one network device which holds both, the IPv4 and the IPv6 address. I have full root access to the machine and no limitations.

How can I route the traffic (any traffic, really) on a specific port to the IPv6 device as transparently as possible?

Comment: See the answers to https://serverfault.com/questions/276515/use-iptables-to-forward-ipv6-to-ipv4 which suggest using `socat`, `xinetd` or `6tunnel` to forward traffic between v4 and v6 endpoints.  In that case the examples are v6-to-v4 but the changes to do v4-to-v6 should be small and obvious.